# Reusable and safe endothermic reaction

Tags: thermodynamics, safety

I am looking for a reusable endothermic reaction that is safe to both touch and handle, it needs to be able to be stored in a jacket and light enough to do physical activity. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6568/homemade-reactor-for-water-cooling

Answer (score 3):

There are many endothermic *physical processes* such as melting ice or sublimation of solid carbon dioxide $\ce{CO2}$. One should also mention [thermoelectric cooling effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_cooling) (Peltier device), which is is rarely effective in practice, yet still an option.

A suitable endothermic *chemical reaction* would probably be an electrolytic dissociation of certain salts, among which dissolving ammonium nitrate $\ce{NH4NO3}$ in water is probably one of the most well-known and effective examples.

Comment: @Jan I like to see the interaction between the solvent and the compound being dissolved as mostly of a chemical nature, but yes, there is no there is no clear line inbetween. Solvation ability is guided by the nature of the chemical bonds, and the solvent's dielectric constant is also related to its composition and chemical properties.